# Is there anyway to pass parameter from snippet to chunk

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-chunks

I am learning modx and stuck at a point. I want to post "uid" value to next page via POST only and want to set hidden field which will contain "uid" as a value. I believe practically its not allowed to pass values to chunk.
 I want to know whats the proper way so i can get POST data and use that value in chunk ??

**My procedure**

1) I have created resource (document) which contains call to snippet and then chunk

2) snippet contains value retrieved from POST

3) chunk contains a form and fields, I want to inject that POST value in this form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this.

1) Return the uid value directly from the snippet (let's call it **getPostData**), and place the snippet call in your hidden field in the chunk like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="[[!getPostData]]" />
```

Note the snippet is uncached (`[[!` opening tag) otherwise the first form submission will be cached.

2) Place the snippet call in the chunk tag and have the value passed into a placeholder:

```
[[$myChunk?uid=`[[!getPostData]]`]]
```

...and in your chunk set an uncached placeholder for 'uid':

```
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="[[!+uid]]" />
```

3) **Recommended:** Use `setPlaceholders()` in your snippet to output content to placeholders anywhere in your page - you can use it to output to multiple placeholders:

```
<?php
// please sanitise your POST values, this is just an example
$placeholders = array();
$placeholders['uid'] = $_POST['uid'];
$placeholders['email'] = $_POST['email'];

$modx->setPlaceholders($placeholders);
```

...and your chunk:

```
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="[[!+uid]]" />
<input type="email" name="email" value="[[!+email]]" />
```

Documentation: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/modX.setPlaceholders

Comment: It worked. I tried 1st and third method both worked. But as per your recommendation i will go with third solution. million thanks